# Performance: Utility class vs. CDI bean

Tags: java, performance, cdi, weld

I want to externalize commonly used applicationlogic into a "utility class" called **Helper**. The applicationlogic needs other CDI beans to work.

Two possibilities:

a)

```
@SessionScoped
class ControllerWithCdiBean {

  @Inject
  Helper helper;

  public void doIt() {
      Object result = helpder.calculate();
  }
}

@RequestScoped
class Helper{

  @Inject
  Service anyService;

  public Object calculate() {
     return anyService.calc();
  }
}
```

b)

```
@SessionScoped
class ControllerWithStaticCallsViaDeltaspike {

  public void doIt() {
      Object result = Helpder.calculate();
  }
}

class Helper{

  private static Service anyService = BeanProvider.getContextualReference(Service.class);

  public static Object calculate() {
     return anyService.calc();
  }
```

What about **performance**? Are there any notable differences? Both solutions are possible for me, is one solutions *better* than the other?

One disadvantage: 
Helpder gets initialized for **every** Request.

Comment: I would go with **a**. Utility classes are evil

Comment: @SvetlinZarev you mean that classes like `java.util.Arrays`, `java.util.Collections` and the whole Apache Commons Xyz libraries are evil? You sure never have used them :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There is a difference. `Arrays` and `Collections` come with the JRE while `Helper` does not. Also the excessive use of static methods (hence utility classes) leads to procedural code and makes it hard to test. The excessive use of utility classes is against the principles of OOP and TDD and should be avoided when possible and in OP's case it;s definitely possible not to use  a utility class.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev good theory, but sadly doesn't apply for all real world apps. There are use cases where your methods will be used in several classes and do the same thing, so it's a good idea to package these methods in a class (or group of classes) that doesn't need an specific instance to make the method work e.g. validate if a `String` is empty or `null`. There are people aware of this and use them in their libraries: Apache Commons family: Lang, IO, etc. Guava, cglib, and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your `Helper` class as `@ApplicationScoped`. With this, you will have a single instance per application context.

Still, if it's just an utility class, it shouldn't be a managed bean at all. I would instead mark it as `final`, define a `private` constructor and mark all the methods as `static`. This is because since it's an utility class, it doesn't need to maintain any state.

Comment: Could problems arise with "private static Service anyService" because I inject a reference (=proxy) to a CDI bean only once and let it there for the whole lefetime of the Helper?

Comment: Then you don't have an utility class but a proxy class. If that's your purpose, then use approach A and mark your proxy as `@ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: Apache Commons Xyz classes are definitely helpful... But after all, I think, that my _Helper_ is more than this. It contains "more" logic, which is not reusable in _all_ cases. So I would rather go with approach a) and make it @ApplicationScoped. This has advantages with component test, although there are frameworks like Powermock which make it easy to test static methods.